# How to insert into column where otherColumn Equal someValue using Nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

First of all , excuse my low knowledge in Hibernate (I'm a sql fan) , I've done many research and I just can't find how to properly do this below

**What I would like to do**   :I Have a table called ClassCodes and I want to  insert each Equivalence code next to his original code

So my 2 columns are Originalcode and Equivalencecodes (Let's assume Originalcode are already filled)

Here is the function I would love to have help

```
public void addEquivalenceCodes(string Code, string EquivalenceCode)
    try
                    {
                        using (ISession session = OpenSession())
                        {
                            using (ITransaction transaction =session.BeginTransaction())
                            {
     //**Here is what I don't know how to write properly in hibernate
 String hql = "INSERT INTO ClassCodes(CodeEquiv)" + "VALUES ("+EquivalenceCode+") WHERE Originalcode = "+Code+";
                    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);          
                                transaction.Commit();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }
                }
```

Here is my mapping , to add more visual help

```
 <class name="ClassCodes, table="[T0101_ClassCode]" lazy="false">
<id name="Id" column="[Id]">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="OriginalCode" column="[OriginalCode]" />
<property name="EquivalanceCode" column="[EquivalanceCode]" />
etc...
```

I appreciate all guides , tips and explication I can get !

Comment: Please share your database table schema.  A DTD statement (`CREATE TABLE ...`) would be a fine way to share it.  PS: This can be done entirely in a SQL statement, regardless of the programming environment.

Comment: @Lotharyx Thank you for taking time to read my question , I edited my post to include  my database mapping (I use HBM files ) and You are write it's very simple using pure sql but I'm forced to respect the nhibernate type of command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not an insert it's an update.

```
using (var session = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession())  
        {  
            ClassCodes classcodes=session.Get<ClassCodes>(Originalcode);

            classcodes.EquivalanceCode="EquivalanceCode value";

            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())  
            {  
                session.SaveOrUpdate(classcodes);  
                transaction.Commit();  
            }  
        }
```